# How to eliminate the unwanted 0s when using for loop(MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab

As the title, I write these codes:

```
for n=1:2:10
    a(n)=2^n;
end
disp(a)
```

I'd like to get the answer

```
a = 2 8 32 128 512
```

but the output in the command window is

```
a = 2 0 8 0 32 0 128 0 512
```

The four 0s are unwanted, and how can I eliminate those four 0s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to remove 0's

- Method 1:

```
a = [];
for n=1:2:10
    a(end+1) = 2^n;
end
```

- Method 2:

```
for n=1:2:10

a(n)=2^n;

end
a = a(a>0);
```

- Method 3:

```
for n=1:2:10
    if mod(n,2)==1
        a((n+1)/2) = 2^n;
    end
end
```

Comment: when `n=3`, then `n/2` will be `1.5` which cannot be used as a linear indice.

Comment: @obchardon sorry for the error, now I fixed my code

Answer (score 2):

When you use a [linear index](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html) that does not start with 1 or miss some value, matlab fill the gap with some `0`:

So you can use the indice `end+1`:

```
a = [];

for n=1:2:10
   a(end+1)=2^n;
end
```

`end` indicate last array index, so `end+1` create a new entry in your array.

But for something that simple it certainly easier to vectorize the process:

```
a = 2.^(1:2:10)
```

Where `.^` is the element-wise power operator.